# Insert image from AWS S3 fails (with SSL)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cross-domain

I use the Summernote WYSIWYG editor for content in a PHP project, but have recently run into a hard to solve problem. Images and other assets are stored at Amazon S3, with a pretty standard bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::fake-bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So the PHP project has an controller method which handles the upload to S3, from a POST request in the backend. This works - I get a full URL back and can manually paste this into the browser and it works. This is implemented in the Summernote editor with a function that creates the image element, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{{ route('admin.api.image-upload') }}',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        var imageElement = document.createElement('img');
        imageElement.src = response._url;
        imageElement.setAttribute('data-id', response.id);
        imageElement.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
        imageElement.className = 'story-image';
        $('#editor-story').summernote('editor.insertNode', imageElement);
    }
});
```

Now, when testing this in my local environment - it works. The image is uploaded, a JSON object with URL is return and inserted correctly into the editor.

*But* when I try this in production, which runs on LetsEncrypt SSL certs, the image (which is uploaded to S3) cannot be properly inserted into the editor:

[image: When uploading image in production]

The way this works is that when I save the story, it saves HTML contents and reloads the page. Now the image is visible:

[image: After saving, it works]

Now, I figure this has something to do with creating DOM elements on one site with contents from another SSL host (S3), but adding a CORS policy doesn't fix the issue:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

In my "Network" tab in the inspector, I get the following request data when creating the element dynamically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>[requestId]</RequestId><HostId>[hostId]</HostId></Error>
```

Comment: shouldn't the method be PUT instead? Also you need to use regions I think http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: Do you mean PUT in the CORSConfiguration? Surely this is a GET request, not an update to an object?

Comment: Is there a reason you omitted `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>` from your CORS configuration?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've tinkered with the CORS configuration a few times; AllowedHeader does not seem to make a difference unfortunately. (The request headers are also identical - but one returns 403 and the other 200.)

Comment: Actually, 200 vs 403 is quite a difference. As a test, put it back to where you get the 200 response, then add `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store` to the metadata of the object in S3 (you can do this in the console).  Ensure that your browser cache is clear, then test again.  There is a bug in S3 that I believe you may be encountering, and preventing the browser from caching the image using S3 metadata will cause it to work, if that's the problem.  I'm not saying you'll keep it that way, but just as a test.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I might not have described my issue correctly, but the upload of images to S3 works. Every time. It is the rendering of the image as an img element that doesn't work correctly. When I use JS to createElement and set src attribute, the response is for some reason 403. If I just render this serverside as HTML (by loading HTML contents from database and outputting it), it works.

Comment: Yes, I understand that exactly.  There is an issue with S3 where it does not return a `Vary: Origin` header under certain conditions in a CORS environment, causing the browser to refuse to load the object.  Disabling browser caching will suppress the incorrect behavior, proving whether this is the problem you are experiencing.  Add `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>` back to the CORS config, set the `Cache-Control` header, clear your browser cache, and if the issue goes away we can conclude that this is the cause and proceed to a solution or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed here:
https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/72

Comment: No, that appears to discuss how to upload files to S3 through Summernote.